# How do you copy a datetime field from the current document to a new document

Tags: xpages, xpages-ssjs

How do you copy a datetime field from the current document to a new document in Xpages, SSJS.

I am coping other fields like this

```
inheritDoc.appendItemValue("AbbreviatedCustomer",currentDocument.getValue("AbbreviatedCustomer"));
var item:NotesItem = inheritDoc.replaceItemValue("Author", n1); item.setNames(true);
item = inheritDoc.replaceItemValue("AuthorAccess", currentDocument.getValue("AuthorAccess")); item.setAuthors(true);
```

But I do not know how to copy a date field from the currentDocument to the inheritDoc.
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to care about data types copying fields (=Items) from one document to an other if you use

```
inheritDoc.copyItem(currentDocument.getDocument().getFirstItem("FieldName"))
```

or

```
inheritDoc.replaceItemValue("FieldName", currentDocument.getDocument().getFirstItem("FieldName"))
```

Fields in target document will have same data type, content and properties as in source document.

Comment: If i use copy item I get the following error      'getFirstItem(string)' on an object of type 'NotesXspDocument [Static Java Wrapper, com.ibm.xsp.model.domino.wrapped.DominoDocument]'                      if i use replaceItemValue I get     Error calling method 'getFirstItem(string)' on an object of type 'NotesXspDocument [Static Java Wrapper, com.ibm.xsp.model.domino.wrapped.DominoDocument]'    thanks for your help

Comment: @user2478462: added ".getDocument()" like you mentioned in comment. You should put "currentDocument.getDocument()" in a "var sourceDoc", use "sourceDoc" in copyItem() and recycle it at the end "sourceDoc.recycle()".

Answer (score 0):

Try using toJavaDate():

```
inheritDoc.replaceItemValue("DateField", currentDocument.getValue("DateField").toJavaDate());
```

Comment: You dont explicitly use the javadate. It should be enough to use the good old copyitem method.

Comment: using .toJavaDate()); Resulted in the following error       [TypeError] Error calling method 'toJavaDate()' on an object of type 'Date [JavaScript Object]'  here the line of code   inheritDoc.replaceItemValue("CloaseDate",currentDocument.getValue("CloseDate").toJavaDate());

Comment: The answer was given by Per and Nathan  
inheritDoc.copyItem(currentDocument.getDocument().getFirstItem("CloseDate"))

Comment: It was Paul and Nathan :-)